# ASP.NET не имеет права обращаться к запрошенному ресурсу

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

В контроллере обращаюсь к сетевой папке

**Work201615Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFor3Class(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
        {
            if (upload != null)
            {
                //получаем расширение файла                
                string fileExten = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName);
                //сохраняем файл в папку Files в проекте
                upload.SaveAs(@"\\192.168.88.220\файлы_пто\Работы\[2016-15] - ДР в 1-3 классов\3 класс\3_кл_Сбор\" + User.Identity.Name + fileExten);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Select");
        }
```

Когда запускаю проект в тестовом режиме все работает нормально. Но когда публикую проект на сервер (сервер - другой компьютер). То оттуда жалуется, что не может получить доступ к сетевой папке `\\192.168.88.220\файлы_пто` - выскакивает вот такая абракадабра:

> Отказано в доступе по пути
>   "\192.168.88.220\файлы_пто\Работы[2016-15] - ДР в 1-3 классов\1
>   класс\1_кл_Сбор".
>
> Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего
>   веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных
>   сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода.
>
> Сведения об исключении: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Отказано в
>   доступе по пути "\192.168.88.220\файлы_пто\Работы[2016-15] - ДР в
>   1-3 классов\1 класс\1_кл_Сбор".
>
> ASP.NET не имеет права обращаться к запрошенному ресурсу.
>   Рекомендуется предоставить удостоверению запроса ASP.NET права доступа
>   к этому ресурсу. ASP.NET имеет базовое удостоверение процесса (обычно
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET для IIS 5 или Network Service на IIS 6 и IIS 7, а
>   также удостоверение настроенного пула приложений на IIS 7.5)), который
>   используется, если приложение не олицетворяется. Если приложение
>   олицетворяется через задание ,
>   удостоверением будет служить идентификатор анонимного пользователя
>   (обычно IUSR_MACHINENAME) или идентификатор пользователя запроса с
>   проверенной подлинностью.
>
> Для предоставления ASP.NET прав на запись в файл, щелкните на файле
>   правой кнопкой мыши в окне "Проводник", выберите "Свойства", затем
>   вкладку "Безопасность". Выберите "Добавить" для добавления
>   соответствующего пользователя или группы. Выделите учетную запись
>   ASP.NET и установите флажки для требуемых прав доступа.

Поиск в сети дал понять, что я не первый кто столкнулся с такой проблемой. Вот некоторые решения, которые я попробовал:

- Необходимо добавить пользователя ASP.NET при открытие общего доступа
  к папке `\\192.168.88.220\файлы_пто` . Я так и не смог найти этого пользователя в списке пользователей. На сетевом компьютере `\\192.168.88.220` стоит Windows 8.1.
- В `Пулы приложений` все переключил в режим `Встроенный`. Не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию, пул приложений в новом IIS работает от имени учетной записи `IIS AppPool\(имя пула)`. Так, пул по умолчанию работает от учетной записи `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool`. Но эта учетная запись существует только на сервере.

Для того, чтобы можно было получить доступ к файлам на другом компьютере, надо запускать пул приложений от имени доменной учетной записи. Зайдите в дополнительные параметры пула приложений, и в категории "Модель процесса" задайте правильное удостоверение.

[image: картинка]

Если же домена нет - то надо перед доступом к сетевой папке [залогиниться](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023607/how-to-use-logonuser-properly-to-impersonate-domain-user-from-workgroup-client) на удаленном компьютере.