# HttpPostedFileBase SaveAs права доступа в расшаренную папку

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Пытаюсь сохранить `HttpPostedFileBase` файл в расшаренную папку на другом севрере ( не на котором IIS), получаю ошибку, что нет прав доступа. 
Как заставить запрашивать логин/пароль или задать их в коде?

```
file.SaveAs(saveFilePath);
```

`Отказано в доступе по пути "\\data\work\..`

Использую asp.net mvc
Платформа Microsoft .NET Framework, версия:4.0.30319; ASP.NET, версия:4.8.3928.0,
IIS 7
На сервере, куда сохраняю файл, Linux, что за линукс пытаюсь пока выяснить.
TS451U QNAP NAS

Если просто зайти через Explorer по пути \data\work.. то достаточно просто ввести логин и пароль в стандартное окно windows

Пробую использовать [NetworkConnetion](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Connecting-to-Remote-f69b9346/sourcecode?fileId=25381&pathId=564469262) Получаю тоже самое. Хотя исключение NetworkConnetion не выбрасывает, значит подключился.

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512740/asp-net-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%83) сказано, что нужно залогиниться на удаленном компьютере. Пока пытаюсь понять как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне [это](http://cstruter.com/blog/270) помогло

Только
`LogonType.Interactive` заменил на `LogonType.NewCredentials`

Вот что у меня вышло в итоге:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr token);

enum LogonType
{
     Interactive = 2,
     Network = 3,
     Batch = 4,
     Service = 5,
     Unlock = 7,
     NetworkClearText = 8,
     NewCredentials = 9
}


enum LogonProvider
{
    Default = 0,
    WinNT35 = 1,
    WinNT40 = 2,
    WinNT50 = 3
}
private string SaveFile(ProjectModel project)
{
    var file = project.File;           

    string directory = $@"\\data\work\...\{DateTime.Now.Year}\";

    string saveFilePath = CreateFilePath(file, directory, project);

    IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool valid = LogonUser(Properties.Settings.Default.login,
                        directory,
                        Properties.Settings.Default.pass,
                        (int)LogonType.NewCredentials,
                        (int)LogonProvider.Default,
                        ref token);
    if (valid)
    {
        using (WindowsImpersonationContext context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token))
        {
             CloseHandle(token);    
             if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                 Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);    

             file.SaveAs(saveFilePath);
         }
     }
     else
     {              
          throw new IOException("Error connecting to remote share");
     }      


     return saveFilePath;
}
```

Comment: сейчас сделаю..